# Use REGEX in user input variable in SQL Query.

Tags: php, sql, regex

I have to write a sql query with a where clause  which  looks for  user input  values in database table.

Say a user input a job title "Head of  science and maths"

The  query should   look for  all the words in a job title individually, and return department list accordingly.

```
$keyword =  mysql_real_escape_string($keyword);

SELECT distinct departments.name FROM departments, jobtitle_keywords 
WHERE jobtitle_keywords.keywords REGEXP   '$keyword' 
AND departments.id = jobtitle_keywords.dept_id;
```

This query runs perfectly in ideal situations( no special characters , spaces etc ) but fails  otherwise

can  anyone  guide me to a proper way to escape  all kinds of special characters and anomalies a user can input so  my query does not fail.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what the `REGEX` is for? You should read the Documentation on that: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: Yes I do know the use of REGEX and i thought it suits my requirement well. Is there any other way I can write a intelligent search  query, which handles user inputs well ?

Comment: If you do know the use of REGEX, why would you put your keyword like that and not `keywords LIKE '%$keyword%'`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: Let me rephrase my question user can input jobtitle like these  head of science and maths  *head of science & maths *head of science/maths  *head of science / maths      *head of science,maths etc ..  The SQL query should  be something similar to    SELECT distinct departments.name FROM departments, jobtitle_keywords 
WHERE jobtitle_keywords.keywords like 'head' or  like 'maths' or like 'science'  AND departments.id = jobtitle_keywords.dept_id;I want to search complete words not patter matching thats why i omitted % in lik e ..    suggestions please.

Comment: Any Help would be greatly appreciated. I am stuck here and have to get it sorted.. Thanks In advance#

Comment: how about using regex in php (i.e. `preg_replace` to get the words out of your search string and then use them to build a `LIKE '%$key[0]%' OR LIKE '%$key[1]% ...` or `LIKE '%$key[0]%' AND LIKE '%$key[1]% ...` query part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So taken your comments i assume you want to take the single words from your users search input (*i.e "head of science / math"*) and use only the words (*head, of, science and math*) and use those to search for in your `jobtitle_keywords.keywords` field.

Assuming this is what you want/need:

Use a [simple regex](http://regex101.com/r/tP1sY4) to make sure you get all words out of your query like this:

```
$re = '/(\w+)/i'; 
$str = 'head of science / math'; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

now in $matches[0] you have your results: `array( "head", "of", "science", "math")`. [Awfully simple](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

Now use this to create an SQL Statement using either `AND` or `OR`. You can do so easily using [`implode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
$queryAddon = "jobtitle_keywords.keywords LIKE '%" 
   . implode ("%' AND jobtitle_keywords.keywords LIKE '%", $matches[0])
   . "%'";
```

Gives you `jobtitle_keywords.keywords LIKE '%head%' AND jobtitle_keywords.keywords LIKE '%of%' AND jobtitle_keywords.keywords LIKE '%science%' AND jobtitle_keywords.keywords LIKE '%math%'`.

[Like stealing a Childs Candy right?](https://eval.in/148008)

So now just put that in your Query and fire it up.

```
$query = "SELECT distinct departments.name FROM departments, jobtitle_keywords "   ."WHERE departments.id = jobtitle_keywords.dept_id "   ." AND (" . $queryAddon . ")";
```

This should do the trick for you - if i got you right.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for ..Thanks for a very detailed explanation along with  the solution. thanks a tone. Will give it  a try and  let you know.

Comment: @user3607604 You're welcome. Appreciation can be shown by upvoting the Answer. Also, mark it as **accepted** (green arrow under the voring pannel) if it did solve your problem so this question will not get any more unneeded attention.

Comment: Hi Andresch, using $re = '/(\w+)/i';   my query is returning the following  result,    jobtitle_keywords.keywords LIKE '%head%' OR jobtitle_keywords.keywords LIKE '%20of%' OR jobtitle_keywords.keywords LIKE '%20science%  How can i get rid of the spaces ??  Tried doing $matches = array_filter(array_map('trim',$matches)); but  its giving error .. Thanks in  advance

Comment: I fail to see any spaces :-/ What spaces do you mean? Would you mind asking a new question?

Comment: I meant the "20" added  to  each array value, its that  each space in the search string  is replaced   with 20.  I'll ask another question fot it. Just a thought. anyone looking at your earlier solution   which was  really help full may get the same issue of  handling spaces. Thanks

Comment: It works in [the example](https://eval.in/148008) i linked in my answer. What did you do different/wrong? Seems a bit like you urlencoded the user input, so ` of ` is `%20of%20` so the regex extracts the `20` with the keyword as `20of`. Did you escape the user input somehow?

Comment: Probably your [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) causes this.

Comment: Thanks  a lot,urldecode did the trick. Sorry iam unable to upvote your answer,being a new member. But your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @user3607604 i suggest you find out why your input was url encoded. might be a thing good to know :D anywho - have a nice day